# How to convert XML to tag value pairs using Tcl

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, tcl

I have an XML like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Request OrderType="ADD_SUB" TransactionId="XMLTXN000000299" Priority="1">
  <ApplicationKeyValues>
    <Key KeyName="TESTID" KeyValue="GT_SYS_001"/>
  </ApplicationKeyValues>
  <ServiceChangeRequest Operation="Activate" SubscriberKey="704020328567323" AlternateSubscriberKey="50223101123">
    <RequiredServices>
      <ServiceDescription ServiceTag="GSMSUB">
        <ParameterDesc ParameterTag="IMSI" ParameterValue="704020328567323"/>
        <ParameterDesc ParameterTag="MSISDN" ParameterValue="50223101123"/>
      </ServiceDescription>
      <ServiceDescription ServiceTag="AER1"/>
    </RequiredServices>
  </ServiceChangeRequest>
</Request>
```

This is my first time with TCL script. The script should convert any similar XML to tag value pairs . Please help

Want it to look like something like this

```
{{ORDERTYPE "ADD_SUB"} {TRANSACTIONID "RMI020222983029285"} {PRIORITY "7"}{APPLICATIONKEYS { { IMSI "704020328567330" } { MSISDN "50223101130" }} }{SERVICEREQUEST{{ OPERATION "ADD" }{ KEYS { { IMSI "704020328567330" } { MSISDN "50223101130" }} }{SERVICES { {GSMSUB{ { MSISDN "50223101130" }{ OPERATION "ADD" }{ IMSI "704020328567330" }{ KI "A3E60077BDDF73C4425E371C90E0C0E6" } } }{AN7D{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{VMAS{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{VC3G{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{AMMS{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{CAMP{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{ALLE{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{AROA{ { OPERATION "ADD" } } }{CINR{ { RSA "2" }{ OPERATION "ADD" } } }}}} } }
```

Comment: I'm no XML expert, but you probably want to look at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tDOM .

Comment: This would be easier to answer if your original XML string and your desired output correspond more closely.  For example, the transaction id is either XMLTXN000000299 or RMI020222983029285.   Priority is either 1 or 7.

Comment: The below tag value pair is an example. I need to convert an XML like above(can be any similar one) to tag value like below.

Comment: This is going to be a messy transformation in any case, as it is not just a "pick the values out of the right places in the input" job; sometimes you seem to need the names of attributes as well as their values. I agree that tDOM is recommended, especially as it has decent XPath support. Not writing an answer right now; not on a development machine...

Comment: I have tried tdom and failed as I have no experience in using it

Comment: Failing to make tDOM run cries for opening another question. Make sure to report all details on what you tried and how the attempt failed.

Answer (score 3):

tDOM is your friend, especially tDOM's [asList](http://www.tdom.org/index.html/doc/trunk/doc/domNode.html) method:

> Returns the DOM substree starting form the current node as a nested Tcl list

Watch:

```
% package req tdom
0.9.2
% set doc [dom parse $str]
domDoc0x7feeebc06ef0
% set root [$doc documentElement]
domNode0x7feeebc07ae0
% $root asList
Request {OrderType ADD_SUB TransactionId XMLTXN000000299 Priority 1} {{ApplicationKeyValues {} {{Key {KeyName TESTID KeyValue GT_SYS_001} {}}}} {ServiceChangeRequest {Operation Activate SubscriberKey 704020328567323 AlternateSubscriberKey 50223101123} {{RequiredServices {} {{ServiceDescription {ServiceTag GSMSUB} {{ParameterDesc {ParameterTag IMSI ParameterValue 704020328567323} {}} {ParameterDesc {ParameterTag MSISDN ParameterValue 50223101123} {}}}} {ServiceDescription {ServiceTag AER1} {}}}}}}}
```

That said, as it has been pointed out to you, once having consumed your XML string using tDOM, you will not need the nested-list structure. You would rather use the tDOM structure to access the data of interest.